# How can I size imageboxes to the image dimensions in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, resize

How can I size imageboxes to the image dimensions in Crystal Reports?
  i am doing a project in tat i having 3 type of  image with different size from db how can i set image

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at the intent of the question and make an edit...cover me boys, I'm going in.

Comment: I think I captured the essense of the babby...

Comment: possible duplicate of [crystal reports image squashed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254260/crystal-reports-image-squashed)

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.crystal/2007-03/msg00039.html)

To make the image resize properly, you must perform the following steps in order:

1. **Set the image's EnableCanGrow to true**
2. **Calculate and set Width and Height to the needed size**
3. **Set the image's EnableCanGrow to false**
4. Fill the DataSet's image object with data
5. Continue with normal report processing.

If you get these items in the wrong order, or skip an item, you will
find that Crystal Reports scales the image in unexpected and unrecoverable ways.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  I managed to solve it by File > Report Options > Retain Original Image Color Depth.  For some reason Crystal sees the altered background colour as part of the image so when you resize it it doesn't alter the background.  By removing the background it gets you around this issue in some instances.