# Does Crystal Report internally re-size the images?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report for Preview purpose. I need to include image in the report. I am passing this image by dataset in the form of byte[]. I have set XScaling = 1.917 and YScaling = 1.917. Still I am getting images in the preview with not same aspect ratio as the original image. What I am doing wrong? Does Crystal Report changes something?

Thank you in Advance..!!

Comment: Do you have the "Can Grow" property enabled on the image in CR?

Comment: @AlecHenderson_v1.00: No I have "Can Grow" property false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crystal reports image squashed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254260/crystal-reports-image-squashed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

To make the image resize properly, you must perform the following steps in order:

1. Set the image's EnableCanGrow to true.
2. Calculate and set Width and Height to the needed size.
3. Set the image's EnableCanGrow to false.
4. Fill the DataSet's image object with data.
5. Continue with normal report processing.